# Python extract folder from zip file with spaces in name

Tags: python, zip

Currently I'm writing a python script which extracts files from a zip file. For this I'm using the ZipFile module. Everything works great for files but I have a problem with folders which contains spaces in their name.

My zip file has following structure:

```
Test.zip
 - foo/test.txt
 - foo bar/test.txt
```

My code to extract the files looks like this:

```
currentFile = ZipFile(zipFilePath, 'r')

currentFile.extractall(path, 'foo/')
currentFile.extractall(path, 'foo bar/')
```

But the second call generates following error:

> KeyError: "There is no item named 'b' in the archive"

I think this reffers to the 'b' of bar. So do you have any ideas why the second call does not work or how I should escape the space character in the folder name to extract it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error by myself. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall):

> ZipFile.extractall([path[, members[, pwd]]])
>
> Extract all members from the archive to the current working directory. path specifies a different directory to extract to. members is optional and must be a subset of the list returned by namelist(). pwd is the password used for encrypted files.

Subset of the list referes back to a list. So I tried:

```
currentFile.extractall(path, ['foo bar/'])
```

and it worked great. Hope it will help someone. Also notice that path and members is reversed in comparison to the `extract` method!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the path with r"string" instead of single quotes. Untested - just going from memory..

```
currentFile.extractall(r"foo bar/", path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the path within an array:

```
currentFile.extractall(path, ['foo bar/'])
```

Comment: Thank you for this that worked. But now I have a new problem: The `namelist()` method does not list my directories. Any ideas for that?